# Generated resource output not found in test classpath in gradle build

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers

I am attempting to configure a gradle (version 4.6) build (as a part of a multi-module project) that uses a Java "script" to generate resources into the main sourceSet, which are then referenced in my test configuration. The idea is that I'd ultimately like to create a jar that is simply a resource bundle for inclusion in another module of my build, but I have java files both to generate these resources and to execute verification tests on them before packaging.

I currently have three sourceSets configured: the standard "main" and "test", and a custom sourceSet "generator" which holds resources used as inputs to the generator "script" and the source for the generator script itself. I've registered a main output directory according to [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html) documentation (see "working with generated resources"), pointing to a JavaExec class that runs the generator with the "generator" sourceSet runtime classpath to output resources into the main classpath.

All of this appears to work- I can find the output in the correct directory when running `:<module>:build`, showing that the script is both running properly and that it is done as a dependency to the main compile task. However, when I try to reference the generated output in the tests with `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("<baseGeneratedOutputDirectory>")`, I get a null value back, suggesting that my generated output is not being included in the test runtime classpath. The documentation clearly states that the...

> Java plugin will use those dirs in calculating class paths and for jarring the content

...so I'm not sure why my files aren't getting picked up. Below is my abridged build.gradle file. Note that I'm overriding the generator task type in order to set it up with build caching, but I still see this bug with caching turned off.

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    generator {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/generator/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/generator/resources']
    }
    main {
        java
        resources
        output.dir("$buildDir/generated-files/main", builtBy: 'generateConfig')
    }
    test {
        java
        resources
    }
}

dependencies {
    api project(':server:server_protobuf_classes');
    api project(':common:game-config-util')
    api 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.5.1'

    generatorImplementation project(':common:game-config-util')
    generatorImplementation project(':server:server_protobuf_classes');
    generatorImplementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
    // ...

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version: '1.3'
    testCompile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.2'
    // ...
}

task generateConfig(type: GenerateConfig) {
    outputs.dir("$buildDir/generated-files/main")

    classpath sourceSets.generator.runtimeClasspath
    main = "com.project.ProtobufConfigurationProcessor"
}

@CacheableTask
class GenerateConfig extends JavaExec {
}
```

EDIT: Adding the following makes the tests pass, but I'm confused why I'd need to manually configure the test resource directory like this. Shouldn't the test task pick up build output from the main source set by default?

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        resources.srcDirs = ["$buildDir/generated-files/main"]
    }
}
```